# Autogenerated Key is not returned in @SelectKey in Spring boot application using Mybatis

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, mybatis, spring-mybatis

Autogenerated Key is not returned in @insert in Spring boot application using Mybatis. i have used @SelectKey and @option in @mapper interface. 
spring boot 1.5.10
mybatis - 3.4.5
mybatis-boot- starter -1.3.1
 and using my sql database . 
please anyone help to get auto generated key in controller class .

Comment: Could you provide code sample with your insert? It will be easier to say what's wrong with it.

Comment: i have got the solution:  i used @options annotation. my code is like this.                                                                             @Insert({"insert into contacts(title,firstname,lastname,gender,dateofbirth,dateofjoining,email,phonenumber,profilephoto,address,active) values (#{title},#{firstName},#{lastName},#{gender},#{dateOfBirth},#{dateOfJoining},#{email},#{phoneNumber},#{profilePhoto},#{address},#{active})"  })
 @Options( useGeneratedKeys=true,keyProperty="contactID", keyColumn="contactid")